# How do I make two seperet animations for the same action just with a "Grab" gameobject location changed after walking left?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, 2d

Sorry for the weird wording, but I am making a multiplayer 2d active ragdoll game where when the player isn't moving there is an animation called "PlayerWalk" where there is a gameobject where the ball grabbed is attached to. But, after moving left it is still faced right, I want to make another animation after walking left for the grab gameobject to be flipped on the x. I made the animation but I do not know how to code that.

SUMMARY: I want another animation to play after the player walks left

```
void Update()
{
    // Move the character using the Input System
    float moveInput = movementInput.x;
    if (moveInput != 0)
    {
        if (moveInput > 0)
        {
            anim.Play("WalkLeft");
            StartCoroutine(MoveRight(legWait));
        }
        else
        {
            anim.Play("WalkRight");
            StartCoroutine(MoveLeft(legWait));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        anim.Play("PlayerWalk");
    }
```